# Totally removing Windows Event Logs

Tags: windows, windows-event-log

I am developing an application that creates Windows event logs and writes to them.

However, during development and testing, I created some event logs by mistake, with sources registered to them.

The issue is that only the first 8 characters of the event log name are significant. Now that I have logs with incorrect names, I cannot create the new logs that I need.

Is there any way to totally remove these event logs (and not just clear them)?

I have tried to delete the file `C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\WrongNamedEventLog.evtx`, but with no success.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample? maybe C# and Powershell and/or BAT-CMD scripts?

Comment: @Kiquenet See Powershell example in my answer, updated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do it programmatically, like [this (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twdecbsx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.Delete("WrongNamedEventLog");
```

You don't have to compile a C# application to do it though, just invoke the `Delete(string logname)` method from PowerShell if you like:

```
[System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::Delete("WrongNamedEventLog");
```

Comment: Thanks. There no other way, to just delete it somehow from Windows Administrator UI?

Comment: Not AFAIK. Probably to avoid any accidental deletion of logfiles

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but if I was in your case...
Use regedit to browse this path, and delete your custom bogus logs:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\LogToDelete
Reboot
Then delete the corresponding files from:
C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs
and/or
C:\windows\system32\config

Comment: Thanks. I'll test. However, it would be nice if reboot wasn't involved... :)